# Does DynamoDb allows duplicate sortKey in Index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

Does DynamoDb allows duplicate sortKey in Global Secondary Index and Local Secondary Index.

I have a table with partitionkey and sortKey and want to introduce GSI and LSI with different sortKey attribute, can this attribute have duplicates?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes...

[GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

> In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key
> values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique.

[LSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html)

> In a DynamoDB table, the combined partition key value and sort key
> value for each item must be unique. However, in a local secondary
> index, the sort key value does not need to be unique for a given
> partition key value.